# clean(self) method is not called when if form.is_valid()

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a RegisterUserForm that is bound to a CustomUser (that extends AbstractUser). Before I save the user, I want to check password1 and password2 if they are equal but the clean(self) method is not called. the user is created even if the passwords are not the same.
I have read a lot of questions and tried a lot of things but couldn't find an answer. My code is below

I tried adding an init and a save method but still does not work.

```py
class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1=forms.CharField(label=_("password"), min_length=4)
    password2=forms.CharField(label=_("repeat password"), min_length=4)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1','password2')


        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.full_clean()
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super().clean()
            print("clean is called")
            password1 = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            password2 = form.cleaned_data.get("password2")
            if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
                raise ValidationError('password_mismatch')

            return self.cleaned_data
```

and my view is

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.save()
            email = user.email
            messages.success(request, f'user with {email} created successfully')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = RegisterUserForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form })
```

Comment: I am not sure what your logic is here but I think it should be `if password1 != password2`

Comment: it doesn't reach the logic, the print("clean is called") is not called

Comment: Check the indentation.

Comment: ok that was it, thanks alex, how do I mark it answered?